# Storing value in session vs in DB - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

I am building a team management app in Rails where `:users` has many `:organizations`. I would like for users to be able to switch between organisations and manage them individually without having the `/organizations/:id/` in the URL. Due to Wildcard SSL certificate costs, I would  also like to avoid using subdomains to identify the organization.

As I understand it, this leaves two options:

1. Store the current organization in the DB.
2. Store the current organization in the session.

What would be the best option here?

Thanks

Comment: If you're just not wanting the `id` in the URL, you can use something like [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to create slugs for each `organization`, which can be as random as you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply store it in the session, there's no reason to do it any other way.  I would also create a before_action in the application controller to automatically load the organization into an instance variable available to your controllers and views.